# Change text size of actionbar item in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to change text size of action bar item.
here is my style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/menu_text</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="menu_text">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

this works on android 5 but on android 4 the text size is default and does not change.

Answer (score 1):

in my Project folder res/styles **AppTheme** has a comment as below,

```
<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
```

So you can do it with your app Theme. I have done it via below code,

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i used that but it does not works on both android 4 and 5.